Wordpress & Gatsby website throwing error when pulling graphql data
I've been building brochure sites with Wordpress as a backend and Gatsby as the frontend for years - however i've not done one for a few months.
I came to build a new one last night, and I'm getting errors that i've never seen before referencing my ACF fields.

No amount of googling has helped, and i'm a bit stuck and unsure what to do.
Here's my gatsby-node.js file, which i've basically copied from an old project that worked perfectly:


const path = require('path')
// const { urlMap } = require('./src/utils/urls')

exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  const nodes = await graphql(`
    {
      allWpPage {
        nodes {
          id
          title
          pageBuilderModules {
            fieldGroupName
            pageBuilderModules {
              fieldGroupName
              ... on PageBuilderModulesPageBuilderModulesPageTitleLayout {
                fieldGroupName
                title
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  if (nodes.errors) {
    console.log('houston, we got a problem');
    throw nodes.errors;
  }

  nodes.data.allWpPage.nodes.forEach((page) => {
    // Creates pages
    console.log(`Creating ${page.title} page.`)
    // createPage({
    //   path: page.uri,
    //   component: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/templates/page.js'),
    //   context: { ...page },
    // })
  })

}



And my ACF fields are pretty simple:

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!
